# I am implementing linked list in java, but my code neither gives any error nor produces any output

Tags: java, object, reference

I am implementing linked list in java, but my code neither gives any error nor produces any output.

```
class LinkedList25
{
    Node head;
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int value)
        {
            data = value;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedList25 list = new LinkedList25();
        boolean choice = true;
        list.insertNode(1,list.head);
        list.insertNode(2,list.head);
        list.insertNode(3,list.head);
        list.printList(list.head);
    }
    public void insertNode(int value,Node move)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(value);
        temp.next = move;
        move = temp;
    }
    public void printList(Node move)
    {
        while(move!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(move.data+"->");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple observations

First thing, list.head is not initialized, even though the move variable in insertNode method is assigned reference to new node, it is passed by value, so it does not reflect updated reference back to list.node in main method. You can update insertNode method to return Node and return 'move' back to main method and assign returned value to list.head. as below

```
// in main 
list.head = list.insertNode(1, list.head);
list.head = list.insertNode(2, list.head);
list.head = list.insertNode(3, list.head);

// in insertNode method return the move node back to caller
public Node insertNode(int value, Node move) {
    Node temp = new Node(value);
    temp.next = move;
    move = temp;
    return move;
}
```

Second the printList method gets into infinite loop as move is not traversed to next node

```
// in printList method add move = move.next inside the while loop as below
public void printList(Node move) {
    while (move != null) {
        System.out.print(move.data + "->");
        move = move.next; // ADD THIS LINE TO AVOID INFINTE LOOP
    }
}
```

Above changes should resolve and print the list.

One question, with current code the linked list acts like a stack of values as new value is always inserted before the head. so printList method would print the values in reverse order of inserted values.

Correct way of insertNode method if purpose is stack would be

```
public void insertNode(int value) {
    Node temp = new Node(value);
    if (this.head == null) {
        this.head = temp;
    } else {
        temp.next = this.head;
        this.head = temp;
    }
}
```

If purpose of LinkedList is not to have as a stack but to have it store values in the same order as they are added then insertNode method should be as below

```
public void insertNode(int value) {
    Node temp = new Node(value);
    if (this.head == null) {
        this.head = temp;
    } else {
        Node par = this.head;
        while (par.next != null) {
            par = par.next; 
        }
        par.next = temp;
    }
}
```

In main method, you do not need to pass list.head always, as insertNode method can access head directly as below.

```
list.insertNode(1);
list.insertNode(2);
list.insertNode(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `printList` method:

```
public void printList(Node move) {
    while (move != null) {
        System.out.print(move.data + "->");
    }
}
```

Your `move` Node is always null, so nothing will be printed out. It means that in fact you never initialized `list.head`.

Even if you fix it, please be careful, becuase you will end up with infinite *while* loop - your code will print **move.data ->** forever.